# Connecting Redis microservice in NestJS causes app to get stuck

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I'm trying to set up a simple hybrid app using [Nest's documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application), but the app gets stuck without throwing.

`main.ts`

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';

const logger = new Logger('Main');

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const redisConfig = configService.get('database.redis');

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      url: `redis://${redisConfig.host}:${redisConfig.port}`,
    },
  });

  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  await app.listen(configService.get('app.port'));
}

bootstrap()
  .then(() => logger.log('App running'))
  .catch((e) => logger.error(e));
```

When I comment out `app.startAllMicroservices()` or the code connecting the microservice, the `App running` line is logged, with it, the app is stuck.

I am 100% certain Redis is up and running and responsive, I am using Bull which uses the same config and it runs just fine.

I have tried commenting out everything irrelevant to the above (everything besides the `ConfigModule`) in the `app.module` to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

I am running the latest version of NestJS and its peer dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just resolved a similar issue. As per the time of writing downgrade redis npm package to ^3 from anything high i.e ^4.

From [nestjs microservice redis docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/redis) ***To start building Redis-based microservices, first install the required package (note as of now the supported Redis version is ^3, not the latest ^4)***: